# Pandas: adding "diagonally"

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame where the index is time, but data per row is not homogenous w.r.t. time, as follows:

```
                   obs_TQ       obs_PQ    
year quarter                          
1    1        5499.330651  1655.414960
     2        4650.849431  1807.889632
     3        5417.065129  3352.855656
     4        7771.021167  2343.369804
```

where `obs_TQ` is the observation for this quarter, and `obs_PQ` is the observation for past quarter. I want to sum up observations by quarter, hence the results by quarter are going to be

```
                                   real_obs
year quarter
   1       1      obs_TQ[1,1] + obs_PQ[1,2]
   1       2      obs_TQ[1,2] + obs_PQ[1,3]
```

That is, for each row, I need to add `obs_TQ` from that row to `obs_PQ` from the next row:

```
                     real_obs
year quarter
   1       1      7307.220283
   1       2      8003.705087
```

Is there any efficient vectorized way of doing this? Grouping by the index wouldn't work here as I need to combine data from different groups, and I'm not really aware of any other tool that I could use in this context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something, couldn't you just add TQ to a shifted PQ?

```
>>> (df["obs_TQ"] + df["obs_PQ"].shift(-1)).to_frame("real_obs")
                 real_obs
year quarter             
1    1        7307.220283
     2        8003.705087
     3        7760.434933
     4                NaN
```

Comment: What if I had a third subindex, like `type in [0, 1]`. One way to ensure it would be to preselect `df.query("type == i")` *prior* to executing your command, and iterate over all `i`. Could I alternatively incorporate this in `shift()`?